# Update foreach in foreach c#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

The code snippet shown will compare each element in the first list with one element in the second one. But when the inner foreach finishes, the upper foreach re-enters and the image throws the same guid in both lists.
How can I get it to not do this?

```
   var listDetail = await _repo.GalleryDetail.GetAllAsync(a => a.GalleryId == request.Id);

        request.GalleryDetails.ToList().ForEach(a =>
        {
            if (a.File == null) 
            {
                foreach (var item in listDetail)
                {
                    a.Image = item.Image;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in listDetail)
                {
                    if (item.Image != null && item.Image != "True")
                        item.Image = a.File.DeleteFtp(url: item.Image.Substring(7), 
          cdn).ToString();
                }

                a.Image = a.File.UploadFtp("GalleryDetail", cdn);
            }
        });
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The first `foreach` loop looks odd… inside the loop, the variable `a` NEVER changes. `Item` changes with each iteration… So after the loop finishes would not `a.Image` simply contain the LAST `item`? Would it not be easier to simply grab the last item in the list instead of assigning `a.Image` numerous values then throw them away?

Comment: @JohnG can you give an example please?

Comment: Sure, `a.Image = listDetail.Last().Image;` would do the same

Comment: I don't want to get Last Image. I want it to process without changing its own image registered in the database for each data. @Rafalon

Comment: You are looping over all the images in listDetail and assigning them to a.Image. Every single one of those assignments will be unused and only the last item in lastDetail would ever be used as an image for the variable a

Comment: I know the problem, I'm asking for the solution

Comment: As we don't know what you actually want to do, how do you expect us to give you a solution other than "write your code differently"? Instead of telling us what you don't want your code to do, try telling us what you want it to do

Comment: Synchronizing and updating the image of the request I want with the image field in the listdetail list. In short, I want to update the image field in the database without changing it.

Comment: _”I want to update the image field in the database without changing it.”_ … ? … You have one `foreach` loop defining `a` … `request.GalleryDetails.ToList().ForEach(a => …` … inside that loop… what do you want to happen if `a.File` is `null`? And what do you want to happen if `a.file` is NOT `null`?

Comment: if a.File is null I want to update other fields in GalleryDetail table except image field. What I am trying to do here is to take the data in the image field in the database and synchronize it again, that is to update the image field without changing it.

I added a photo to the question.

Comment: Maybe you could make use of that `Id` field if you want to synchronize anything?

Comment: can you give an example please?  @Rafalon

Comment: Maybe something like `if(item.Id == a.Id){ a.Image = item.Image; }`

Comment: _”if a.File is null I want to update other fields in GalleryDetail table except image field.”_ … Well, the code is already looping through each of the GalleryDetail items and `a` is the current one… what changes are you wanting to make? And I mean no disrespect, but, you really need to clarify what you mean by… _”… that is to update the image field without changing it.”_ … ? … that makes no sense. I am not understanding how you can “update” something “without” possibly “changing” it. Can you show a before/after of what you are describing?

Comment: @Rafalon Thank you if(item.Id == a.Id){ a.Image = item.Image; } this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overwrites `a.Image` for every item in `listDetail`, therefore you get the last `Image`:

```
foreach (var item in listDetail)
{
    a.Image = item.Image;
}
```

As you have an `Id` property, I suggest using it for synchronization:

```
foreach (var item in listDetail)
{
    if (item.Id == a.Id)
    {
        a.Image = item.Image;
        break;
    }
}
```

I added a `break;` so you break out of the loop as soon as you found a match.